# Excel - Adding new column automatically when adding a new cell line

Tags: excel, vba

[image: example]

Hello guys,

Is there any way in excel when adding a new cell line it automatically creates a new column with the same name created in the cenll line?
For example, in the picture I have the line 2:5 with names and columns B:E with the same names, but in case, for instance, I wanted to add a new line called "Legs" between line 2:3 (Head and Nose) and it'd automatically create a new column between B:C (Head and Nose) with the name "Legs".
Is there any way to do this since I don't know VBA?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have pointed out, this can be done in VBA, but if we take a step back, you can actually do it without it. One way to do this without VBA is to use the `TRANSPOSE()` function and a dynamic named range.

Firstly, you need to specify the dynamic range of the source values in column A. Press Ctrl+F3 to go to the Name Manager, Select `New`, give it a name, and in `Refers to` enter the following formula:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),1)
```

Obviously, replace Sheet1 with the name of your worksheet. After you press OK, you should end up with something like this:

[image]

Next, go to cell B1 and type the following formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(sourceHeadings)
```

Replacing the text 'sourceHeadings' with the name of the range you just created a second ago.

That will transpose the headings across the top:
[image]

As you add more to the list in column A, they will appear along the top in row 1.

More reading can be found here on these:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-dynamic-defined-range
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027